# Additional quotes added for font-family value while applying CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, font-family

I am trying to apply font-family CSS dynamically  for a span tag through the following code.

```
    var node = document.getElementsByTagName("span"); 
    $(node).css("font-family","Courier New,Courier,monospace");
```

While doing this, the first part of font-family is wrapped into a double quotes like shown below

```
"font-family: "Courier New", Courier, monospace;"
```

Styles are applied for element but I need to remove this inner double quotes added for the first part of font-family value("Courier New") for processing this HTML in controller end.

Jsfiddle Link: http://jsfiddle.net/uot92ysf/9/

Can anyone suggest me on how to apply font-family style for span tag without this inner quotes or how to remove this quotes after adding CSS?

Regards,

Keerthana.

Comment: I don't think so. that is pattern you can not do that.

Comment: is there a reason for removing the quotes? in W3C standard, you must have it for a valid font-family name value for non-generic font family names: https://drafts.csswg.org/css-fonts-3/#font-family-prop

Answer (score 3):

I think your quote is not effect more. Just read the document

https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/unquoted-font-family

Answer (score 0):

From MDN: [`<family-name>` Values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-family#Values)

> The name of a font family. For example, "Times" and "Helvetica" are font families. ***Font family names containing whitespace should be quoted***.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var node = document.getElementsByTagName("span"); 
$(node).css("font-family",`'Courier New,Courier,monospace'`);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span>Example</span>
```

You can add the property as String object to get rid of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Single quotes around `'Courier New'` will do the job. Example:

EDIT:

When setting the font family in the CSS as per the example it is double quoted. As per the CSS standards. "Font family names must either be given quoted as strings, or unquoted as a sequence of one or more identifiers. This means most punctuation characters and digits at the start of each token must be escaped in unquoted font family names."

Therefore this works in the same way it would if I set it in CSS [JS Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/MatrixMe/y4q2gsz6/2/)

```
$('#button2').click(function() {
    var node = document.getElementById("test"); 

    var font = 'Courier New'; 

console.log($(node).css("background-color")  );
if ( $(node).css("background-color") == "rgb(255, 255, 255)")  {
        $(node).css("background-color", "rgb(255, 0, 0)");
            $(node).css("font-family", font);
    } else {
        $(node).css("background-color", "rgb(255, 255, 255)");
            $(node).css("font-family", "Arial");
    }
});
```

Original response

```
$('#button2').click(function() {
    var node = document.getElementsByTagName("span"); 
    $(node).css("font-family","'Courier New',Courier,monospace");
});
```

Comment: The problem will remain the same. this will add the invalid format of Font name. https://drafts.csswg.org/css-fonts-3/#font-family-prop

Comment: Nope it is done in most JS libraries for example google fonts if you select Roboto Condensed it will provide the following font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif; - https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Roboto+Condensed?selection.family=Roboto+Condensed.